# How do I install Ubuntu in Virtualbox?

Tags: wireless, hp, dv6

I want to install Ubuntu on my hp dv6 3000 within a virtual machine. I did so once with Ubuntu 10.10, but the internet didn't work. A friend recommended I try 9.10. SO I want to give the new release a try, will it work on my computer in a virtual machine? Do I need some kind of special configuration to use it? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to install ubuntu 11.10 in a virtual machine running on windows, or are you asking if ubuntu 11.10 will run on your DV6 and you want to run some sort of virtual machine software?

Comment: If you are wanting to know if Ubuntu will recognize your host hardware, boot the live (desktop) cd and try it. If you have a problem, please identify your hardware (wireless card). Ubuntu should work well as a guest in Virtualbox. If you are running in virtualbox, it should use your wireless card, perhaps a setting in virtualbox.

Comment: People will read the title of your question before deciding whether to bother reading the whole question.  You should edit it to something more meaningful than "should or shouldn't".  (It's not entirely clear just what you're asking, so decide that first.)

Answer (score 2):

First, download the current version of Ubuntu. You can do so [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

Once the file has finished downloading, download VirtualBox. You can do so [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Download the version for Windows hosts.

Once the download has finished, install VirtualBox, then open it. You will see a screen like the following:
[image: screenshot]

Click "New" in the toolbar. In the wizard that appears, click "Next". Name the virual machine and click "Next". Set the memory size to half your ram. Click Next. Make a new virtual hard disk for the VM, I would recommend around 40 gb.
[image]

Finish the wizard by clicking "Create". Double-click the virtual machine in the list in the VirtualBox main window. In the first run wizard, navigate to the iso you downloaded earlier. Follow the on-screen instructions to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the network adapter of your virtual machine software to use NAT. Your virtual machine will use the connection and IP address of your host machine. Ubuntu will see it as a wired network.